# Using NVarChar in asp.net core

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

I'm creating a model for an existing database. How do I use `nvarchar(max)` as an attribute to my property? Do I use an extension to my attribute? Or is it entirely different.

The SQL Server database is using a datatype of `nvarchar(max)`.

```
[MaxLength + ???]
public string Bucket { get; set; }
```

Comment: Which part of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/max-length) do you not understand? Why do you want to set the maxlength for a nvarchar(max) column? What do you think what would happen if you remove that statement?  Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: These answers are perfect. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
public string Bucket { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the attribute as suggested by @JOSEFtw but it's also possible to do with the fluent API if that's how you're defining other properties.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourType>()
                    .Property(p => p.Bucket)
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");
```

Comment: This is cleaner IMO :)